# Can I use docker to automatically spawn instances of whole microservices?

Tags: docker, cloud, docker-compose

I have a microservice with about 6 seperate components.

I am looking to sell instances of this microservice to people who need dedicated versions of it for their project.

Docker seems to be the solution to doing this as easily as possible.

What is still very unclear to me is, is it possible to use docker to deploy whole instances of microservices within a cloud service like GCP or AWS?
Is this something more specific to the Cloud provider itself?

Basicly in the end, I'd like to be able to, via code, start up a whole new instance of my microservice within its own network having each component be able to speak to eachother.

One big problem I see is assigning IP's to the containers so that they will find each other, independent of which network they are in. Is this even possible or is this not yet feasible with current cloud techonology?

Thanks a lot in advance, I know this is a big one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They is definitely feasible and is nowadays one of the most popular ways to ship and deploy applications. However, the procedure to deploy varies slightly based on the cloud provider that you choose.

The good news is that the packaging of your microservices with Docker is independent from the cloud provider you use. You basically need to package each component in a Docker image, and deploy these images to a cloud platform.

All popular cloud platforms nowadays support deployment of docker containers. You can use in addition popular frameworks such as Docker swarm or Kubernetes on these cloud platforms to orchestrate the microservices deployment.

Comment: Thank you for the info! But my main concern is that I have independant images e.g. storage and then dependant ones e.g. controller that uses storage. How will I build a dependant image before deploying the independant ones and make sure they will receive the proper url to connect to the independant ones? The way I understand is that I must first build the independant ones, deploy them, then manually use their IP's and pass them to the dependant builds and only then am I able to deploy the dependant ones. This however is not automated. Does Kubernetes or Docker swarm have solutions to that?

Comment: @ThatBrianDude You can build the docker images independently at first. Then you can use docker-compose to deploy all the instances on you local machine. When using docker-compose, different components can communicate with each other using the service name you give them. Example controller can talk directly to storage using example http://storage:8080/data. Once you get components working with compose, start a docker swarm cluster locally, it will mimick what you would have on a production environment. There are many tools to learn about, so be patient,  you will reach the target that you want.

Comment: Well that seems even simpler than I expected. I will be looking into docker-compose then. Once again I thank you for your time!